sum and count of a dataset with specified bins as criteria
This is a toy data.

library(data.table)
rowlength<-100000

set.seed(10)
Nametypes<-c("A1","B2","C3","D4","E5","F6","G7");
DT<-data.table(DTName1 = sample(Nametypes,rowlength,replace = TRUE),DTName2 = sample(Nametypes,rowlength,replace = TRUE),Criteria1=round(runif(rowlength,min = 0,max = 1)),
           Numeric1=rnorm(rowlength,mean = 1,sd = 100),
           bins=round(runif(rowlength,min = 1,max = 1e9)))
values<-c(0,2,5,7,9,10,12,15,18,20,25,30,35,50,100,150,200,500,Inf)*1e5;
binL<-values[-length(values)];binU<-values[-1];

I want to do exactly as mentioned below: one involves calculating a sum, and the other involves counting, both with multiple criteria.
Input1<-"DTName1";
Input2<-"Numeric1";


sapply(Nametypes, \(j){cbind(sapply(1: 19,\(i)sum(DT[Criteria1==1 & bins>= binL[i] & bins < binU[i] & get(Input1)== j, .(get(Input2))])))})
sapply(Nametypes, \(j){cbind(sapply(1: 19,\(i)nrow(DT[Criteria1==1 & bins>= binL[i] & bins < binU[i] & get(Input1)== j, .(get(Input2))])))})

However, my code is extremely inefficient due to slow processing. In my toy data, I have used only 100K entries, but it may scale up to 5 million.
1.I need the values to display as zero if no criteria are met.
2.Please use only the data.table package.
3.Input1 and Input2 can vary since they come from external sources, which is why I am using the get function. I am unsure if this should be avoided. Alternatives are welcome.

1) We can use tapply and table as shown.  This returns a matrix and a "table" class object each with the intervals specified in the row names.
DT[Criteria1 == 1, tapply(.SD[[Input2]],
    .(cut(bins, values, include.lowest = TRUE), factor(.SD[[Input1]], Nametypes)),
    sum,
    default = 0)]

DT[Criteria1 == 1, table(
  cut(bins, values, include.lowest = TRUE),
  factor(.SD[[Input1]], Nametypes)) ]

1a)  or
DT2 <- DT[Criteria1 == 1][, c("cuts", "DTName1", "DTName2") := 
  .(cut(bins, values, include.lowest = TRUE),
  factor(DTName1, levels = Nametypes),
  factor(DTName2, levels = Nametypes))]

 DT2[, tapply(.SD[[Input2]], .(cuts, .SD[[Input1]]), sum, default = 0)]

##                            A1           B2           C3           D4          E5          F6           G7
## [0,2e+05]           -55.37939      0.00000   152.331295     0.000000   -32.11065   -57.98264   137.752461
## (2e+05,5e+05]       -56.37766    132.72732    30.682194  -103.529421   224.21310   119.04061    -6.906409
## (5e+05,7e+05]        19.43140    201.32557     0.000000   -30.504084     0.00000  -121.27830    48.831916
## (7e+05,9e+05]       -71.53381   -155.44489    -1.853501   -70.497173    82.48696     0.00000   187.066078
## (9e+05,1e+06]       156.18999      0.00000   -51.555027     0.000000  -100.15647  -129.21000     0.000000
## ...snip...

DT2[, table(cuts, .SD[[Input1]])]
               
## cuts                  A1   B2   C3   D4   E5   F6   G7
##   [0,2e+05]            3    0    2    0    1    1    1
##   (2e+05,5e+05]        1    1    1    1    3    2    1
##   (5e+05,7e+05]        2    2    0    1    0    4    1
##   (7e+05,9e+05]        1    4    1    1    2    0    2
##   (9e+05,1e+06]        1    0    1    0    1    1    0
## ...snip...

2) Alternately use dcast.  DT2 is from (1a).  This returns a data frame with a cuts column containing the intervals.
fo <- reformulate(Input1, "cuts")

dcast(DT2, fo, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = Input2, fill = 0, drop = FALSE)

dcast(DT2, fo, fun.aggregate = length, drop = FALSE)

3) xtabs also works.  DT2 is from (1a).  This returns an object of class c("xtabs", "table") with cuts being the intervals as row names.
xtabs(reformulate(c("cuts", Input1), Input2), DT2)

xtabs(reformulate(c("cuts", Input1)), DT2)

Peformance
Comparing the run time of 25 replications of the question's code and each of the alternatives above we see that all the alternatives here are faster than the code in the question and 1a is fastest on this particular test being nearly 2 orders of magnitude faster.  Although x1a is fastest on this particlar test the cld column shows that the difference in timings among x1, x1a, x2 and x3 is not statistically significant.  The difference between any of them and the code in the question is significant.  Based on the timings below I suspect that it now takes under a second to process 5 million rows so you may wish to choose among these based on other considerations.
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(times = 25,
  ques = {
    sapply(Nametypes, \(j){cbind(sapply(1:19,\(i)sum(DT[Criteria1==1 & bins>= binL[i] & bins < binU[i] & get(Input1)== j, .(get(Input2))])))})
    sapply(Nametypes, \(j){cbind(sapply(1:19,\(i)nrow(DT[Criteria1==1 & bins>= binL[i] & bins < binU[i] & get(Input1)== j, .(get(Input2))])))})
  },
  x1 = {
    DT[Criteria1 == 1, tapply(.SD[[Input2]],
      .(cut(bins, values, include.lowest = TRUE), factor(.SD[[Input1]], Nametypes)),
      sum,
      default = 0)]
    DT[Criteria1 == 1, table(
      cut(bins, values, include.lowest = TRUE),
      factor(.SD[[Input1]], Nametypes)) ]
  },
  x1a = {
    DT2 <- DT[Criteria1 == 1][, c("cuts", "DTName1", "DTName2") := 
      .(cut(bins, values, include.lowest = TRUE),
      factor(DTName1, levels = Nametypes),
      factor(DTName2, levels = Nametypes))]
    DT2[, tapply(.SD[[Input2]], .(cuts, .SD[[Input1]]), sum, default = 0)]
    DT2[, table(cuts, .SD[[Input1]])]
  },
  x2 = {
    DT2 <- DT[Criteria1 == 1][, c("cuts", "DTName1", "DTName2") := 
      .(cut(bins, values, include.lowest = TRUE),
      factor(DTName1, levels = Nametypes),
      factor(DTName2, levels = Nametypes))]
    fo <- reformulate(Input1, "cuts")
    dcast(DT2, fo, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = Input2, fill = 0, drop = FALSE)
    dcast(DT2, fo, fun.aggregate = length, drop = FALSE)
  },
  x3 = {
    DT2 <- DT[Criteria1 == 1][, c("cuts", "DTName1", "DTName2") := 
      .(cut(bins, values, include.lowest = TRUE),
      factor(DTName1, levels = Nametypes),
      factor(DTName2, levels = Nametypes))]
    xtabs(reformulate(c("cuts", Input1), Input2), DT2)
    xtabs(reformulate(c("cuts", Input1)), DT2)
  }
)

giving
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 ques 2434.5281 2481.5263 2546.53712 2533.2777 2579.1233 2717.1869    25  a 
   x1   32.4013   35.9994   39.55306   38.2676   42.7410   49.6467    25   b
  x1a   23.0932   26.1382   29.66336   28.3790   32.8300   38.1734    25   b
   x2   43.4468   45.2096   50.95142   47.6681   54.5723   86.3079    25   b
   x3   23.6705   27.3961   30.30350   28.8655   33.5297   40.0132    25   b


tapply gives NA instead of default 0.

Have fixed.  .default should have been default without the dot.  Also added fill=0 to the dcast approach.

Why not DT2 <- DT[Criteria1 == 1][, cuts := cut(bins, values, include.lowest = TRUE)]  (directly)?

That is slightly shorter.  Have made that change.

2 things please, anyways you reply or not to this I will tick this answer. 1. Sometimes some of the Nametypes may not be in the data, I wanted all of the name types to be displayed if not available in the DT then zero. 2. How can I have this displayed as a data.table DT[Criteria1==1 , tapply(.SD[[Input2]], .(cut(bins, values, include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)), sum, default = 0)]

The only changes needed to accommodate that is to make the relevant columns to be factor with Nametypes as the levels and also in (2) to add drop=FALSE since dcast by default drops unused levels.  I have made these changes in the code. Have also added a sentence under Performance that it is likely that any of these now run in under 1 second for 5 million rows so  you may wish to decide among them not on the basis of performance but on other considerations such as the class of the output or based on simplicity.

Find one way to solve your problem below:
Note that the use of get in data.table is outdated (see Programming on data.table) and the programming interface env should be used instead.
D = DT[i = Criteria1==1, 
       j = .(sm=sum(Input2), nr=.N), 
       keyby = .(i=findInterval(bins, values), Input1), 
       env = list(Input1=Input1, Input2=Input2)
      ][, `:=`(binL=values[i], binU=values[i+1L])]

fmla = as.formula(paste0("binL + binU ~ ", Input1))
dcast(D, fmla, value.var="sm", fill=0)       # (a) table with the sum
dcast(D, fmla, value.var="nr", fill=0)       # (b) table with the number of rows



(a)
# Key: <binL, binU>
#      binL    binU          A1           B2           C3           D4          E5          F6           G7
#     <num>   <num>       <num>        <num>        <num>        <num>       <num>       <num>        <num>
#  1: 0.0e+00 2.0e+05   -55.37939      0.00000   152.331295     0.000000   -32.11065   -57.98264   137.752461
#  2: 2.0e+05 5.0e+05   -56.37766    132.72732    30.682194  -103.529421   224.21310   119.04061    -6.906409
#  3: 5.0e+05 7.0e+05    19.43140    201.32557     0.000000   -30.504084     0.00000  -121.27830    48.831916
#  4: 7.0e+05 9.0e+05   -71.53381   -155.44489    -1.853501   -70.497173    82.48696     0.00000   187.066078
#  5: 9.0e+05 1.0e+06   156.18999      0.00000   -51.555027     0.000000  -100.15647  -129.21000     0.000000
#  6: 1.0e+06 1.2e+06     0.00000      0.00000  -285.519179    85.552899    74.90719   250.98759     0.000000
#  7: 1.2e+06 1.5e+06   262.91863   -147.27933    73.757083     1.746635    20.70621   -27.45389   -79.740476
#  8: 1.5e+06 1.8e+06   -86.48851   -109.95476   298.744916  -147.516307    48.94579    56.43557   342.786912
#  9: 1.8e+06 2.0e+06   -12.80383     46.18299   293.129924    90.158802   -74.88664  -264.74663   161.607143
# 10: 2.0e+06 2.5e+06   177.56662    279.37035    40.465047  -121.395825    90.80775   613.28516   300.110347
# 11: 2.5e+06 3.0e+06   -33.59478    153.19853   140.824436  -155.302885    34.65579   107.15395   141.680057
# 12: 3.0e+06 3.5e+06   -25.52025   -163.68711  -110.651548  -146.696664    15.01607   352.42153  -722.328060
# 13: 3.5e+06 5.0e+06   -55.39836    259.13299  -290.578341   -31.952920  -285.56312   -86.00385  -419.498526
# 14: 5.0e+06 1.0e+07  -746.29573   -884.02524  -681.659181  -230.744924   940.58151  -927.77166  -916.594648
# 15: 1.0e+07 1.5e+07   243.05216   -615.64035   -93.920691  -142.435537  -338.29623  -226.50480  -206.952363
# 16: 1.5e+07 2.0e+07   121.55534    322.86362   -10.543726   -76.017209   -23.28971  -330.24830  -331.204901
# 17: 2.0e+07 5.0e+07  1309.40990    715.63485 -2396.120519  -276.423126   481.82817 -2129.73550 -1407.231353
# 18: 5.0e+07     Inf -4975.81496 -14781.12216 23666.159847 -4235.179239 11462.34049  3076.74176 12760.990868


(b)
# Key: <binL, binU>
#      binL    binU    A1    B2    C3    D4    E5    F6    G7
#     <num>   <num> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#  1: 0.0e+00 2.0e+05     3     0     2     0     1     1     1
#  2: 2.0e+05 5.0e+05     1     1     1     1     3     2     1
#  3: 5.0e+05 7.0e+05     2     2     0     1     0     4     1
#  4: 7.0e+05 9.0e+05     1     4     1     1     2     0     2
#  5: 9.0e+05 1.0e+06     1     0     1     0     1     1     0
#  6: 1.0e+06 1.2e+06     0     0     5     3     1     2     0
#  7: 1.2e+06 1.5e+06     3     1     2     1     2     1     2
#  8: 1.5e+06 1.8e+06     2     1     3     3     3     2     4
#  9: 1.8e+06 2.0e+06     2     2     4     2     1     2     2
# 10: 2.0e+06 2.5e+06     4     5     3     4     2     9     4
# 11: 2.5e+06 3.0e+06     2     6     3     5     3     1     5
# 12: 3.0e+06 3.5e+06     5     5     2     6     3     7     5
# 13: 3.5e+06 5.0e+06    13    19     8    11     6    13    15
# 14: 5.0e+06 1.0e+07    35    29    42    43    33    37    39
# 15: 1.0e+07 1.5e+07    32    41    43    47    37    24    36
# 16: 1.5e+07 2.0e+07    37    37    47    38    30    41    28
# 17: 2.0e+07 5.0e+07   216   207   232   204   237   205   213
# 18: 5.0e+07     Inf  6755  6924  6985  6806  6869  6635  6754

changing rowlength<-100000 to rowlength<-5000000 to reflect your actual dataset and rerunning @G. Grothendieck's benchmark gives the result below:
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  times=5L,
  x1a = {
    DT2 <- DT[Criteria1 == 1][, 
                              transform(.SD, cuts = cut(bins, values, include.lowest = TRUE))]
    DT2[, tapply(.SD[[Input2]], .(cuts, .SD[[Input1]]), sum, default = 0)]
    DT2[, table(cuts, .SD[[Input1]])]
  },
  me={
    D = DT[Criteria1==1, .(sm=sum(Input2), nr=.N), 
           keyby = .(i=findInterval(bins, values), Input1), 
           env = list(Input1=Input1, Input2=Input2)
    ][, `:=`(binL=values[i], binU=values[i+1L])]
    fmla = as.formula(paste0("binL + binU ~ ", Input1))
    dcast(D, fmla, value.var="sm", fill=0)       # (a) table with the sum
    dcast(D, fmla, value.var="nr", fill=0)       # (b) table with the number 
  }
)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  x1a 491.5201 494.6190 546.7480 547.8076 574.2607 625.5328     5
   me 131.1393 132.9475 160.3574 146.0710 181.0020 210.6271     5

